# Inconsistent Date field in mongodb , why happen , how to identify and fix

Tags: mongodb

I have identified recently date fields in my mongod 4.0 with such a content:

```
 "last_update" : ISODate("-229-05-06T07:23:23Z")
 "last_update" : ISODate("50170-12-13T06:03:34Z")
 "last_update" : ISODate("0000-07-23T05:19:55Z")
```

So my question:

1. Is mongodb allowing such freedom for date fields ( signed 64bit integer of type date ) ?

According to this :

https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/extended-json.rst#conversion-table

It seems like the format is OK?

Datetime [year before 1970 or after 9999]   {"$date": {"$numberLong": <64-bit signed integer giving millisecs relative to the epoch, as a string>}}

Attempts to insert it from mongo shell ISO date helper as expected did not allowed me:

```
 MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.test.insert({  "created" : ISODate("-229-05-06T07:23:23Z")  })
 2021-01-29T11:47:53.484+0100 E QUERY    [js] Error: invalid ISO date: -229-05-06T07:23:23Z :
 ISODate@src/mongo/shell/types.js:65:1
 @(shell):1:31
 MongoDB Enterprise mongos>
```

But at the same time insert affected fields from the original document in another collection was not having issues:

```
 MongoDB Enterprise mongos> var x = db.theAffectedCollection.findOne({_id:ObjectId("5c6e8c6ce0ebbb309ce0dc06")}, 
{created:1,last_update:1})
 MongoDB Enterprise mongos> use test
 MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.test.insert(x)
 WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
 MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c6e8c6ce0ebbb309ce0dc06"), "created" : ISODate("-229-05-06T07:23:23Z"), "last_update" : ISODate("-229-05-06T07:23:23Z") }
```

mongoexport result:

```
 "created":{"$date":"-0229-05-06T07:23:23.000Z"}
```

Luckily the document _id timestamp show the exact creation date:

```
 ObjectId("5c6e8c6ce0ebbb309ce0dc06").getTimestamp()
 ISODate("2019-02-21T11:33:00Z")
```

So I could easily fix it ...

Comment: `ISODate` is an alias for `new Date` and a function of your mongo shell, i.e. not the "real" data. Export the document with `mongoexport` and see the raw value of it. Perhaps it is year 229 B.C. but mongo shell does not implement it properly.

Comment: Must be related to this smallprint https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#unsigned-date  There was a bit of inconsistency with client drivers switching to BSON v2 so I guess it's "why happened".

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: Added result from mongoexport , it shall not be  from 229 B.C. usually , extracted the date from the document _id and it show: ObjectId("5c6e8c6ce0ebbb309ce0dc06").getTimestamp()
ISODate("2019-02-21T11:33:00Z")  which is the expected creation date ... but still not clear how has  changed ...   , maybe due to this BSON v2 but it seems this change to affect only indexes

Comment: What server version and shell version?

Comment: currently:4.0.19 , at the time of insertion: 3.4

Comment: it seems like since the Date field is stored as signed 64bit Integer  it is allowed dates outside the year range 0000-9999, and ISO constrains apply only the specific language and formats if there is no strict schema validation, so aparrently we can store date like "50923-07-12 01:01:01" and mongodb will not complain...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue clarified , in the extended json format supported by mongoDB the date field in shell mode ( not strict mode ) can support dates outside the range 0000-9999 and it is understood by mongodb like signed 64bit integer in the form:

```
 mongos> new Date(1313124124122341)
 ISODate("43581-03-31T21:08:42.341Z")
 mongos> 
 mongos> new Date(-121213232233222)
 ISODate("-1872-11-27T01:42:46.778Z")
 mongos>
```

In Strict mode,  is an ISO-8601 date format with a mandatory time zone field following the template YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.mmm<+/-Offset>.

In Shell mode,  is the JSON representation of a 64-bit signed integer giving the number of milliseconds since epoch UTC.

Strict Mode:

```
 { "$date": "<date>" }
```

mongo Shell Mode:

```
 new Date ( <date> )
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json-v1/

Internally, Date objects are stored as a signed 64-bit integer representing the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970).

**Not all database operations and drivers support the full 64-bit range. You may safely work with dates with years within the inclusive range 0 through 9999.**

So thanks alot @Alex & @Wernfried to provide the hints !